# Getting wrong route variable value in laravel subdomain route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using this laravel route

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.abc.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('get_user/{user_id}','MyController@myMethod');
}
```

Here , I am getting wrong `user_id` in my controller, It should be something like `15` but I am getting my subdomain value `subdomain_value`

What I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks for your time and advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code  in your controller

```
 $user_id = $request->route()->parameter('user_id');
```

You can access the exact value of route variable from the route parameters.

Comment: Thanks its worked, but why my code was not working ?

Comment: Your question is "What I am doing wrong here ?"                                Answer:: When using subdomain routes, Laravel automatically passes on the subdomain as the first parameter of each method.

Comment: @Arvind, is there an elegant way you can suggest to ignore the `subdomain` parameter passed on every Controller?

Comment: @Valkyrurr Yes. You can create a middleware where you can set url defaults eg `\URL::defaults([
            'subdomain' => $request->route('subdomain'),
        ]); `
You can the add this middleware to the route middleware groups